# How to enter stored procedure parameters correctly in Informix?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, informix

I have a stored procedure below using dbaccess:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_1 (p_name VARCHAR(20), 
p_usernum INTEGER)
RETURNING CHAR(7);
DEFINE err INTEGER;

ON EXCEPTION SET err
RETURN 'ERROR';
END EXCEPTION

ON EXCEPTION IN (150) SET err
RETURN 'NOTHING';
END EXCEPTION

INSERT INTO database1 (name, usernum,)
VALUES (p_name, p_usernum,);

IF DBINFO('sqlca.sqlerrd2') = 0
      THEN RAISE EXCEPTION 150;
   END IF;

RETURN 'YES';
END PROCEDURE;
```

....
I am getting an error -201 when the stored procedure is ran.
Is the next line causing after the first parameter the error?
Is there a proper way to allow parameters to move to the next line in stored procedures?
What am trying to do is run a stored procedure with INSERT and to return back error information if the INSERT is unsuccessful as well.

Comment: Are you using `dbaccess` or `isql` to run the SQL?  Using `isql` won't work because it doesn't recognize that multiple statements must be sent.  However, judging from the conversation you are probably using `dbaccess` and then the syntax error described in the answer is your main problem.

Comment: Yes, I am using dbaccess, looking at my stored procedure I am not sure where the syntax is having a problem...

Comment: The code suggested by Ricardo Henriques works for me.  One place where you've got a syntax error is in your line `DEFINE err;` which is missing the type information.  Since you never use the value in `err`, you could simply omit it and the `SET err` clauses.  You have subtle issues with the general `ON EXCEPTION` taking precedence over `ON EXCEPTION IN (150)` (or `IN (746)`) so you only get `ERROR`, not `NOTHING`.  You also never get a successful INSERT that doesn't insert one row (when you use the VALUES list), so the `IF DBINFO('sqlca.sqlerrd2') = 0` condition will never fire.

Comment: Despite the err not having a type defined and the custom exception, which I believe I understand, why does VALUES keyword not allow for an insert?

Comment: VALUES does allow an INSERT; indeed, it insists that there must be an INSERT or it will fail with an exception.  Unless my memory is letting me down again, your post-INSERT check is looking for 'no row was inserted' when in fact 'one row must have been inserted'.  So the post-insert check is redundant; it will never be activated.  It might be relevant if you used `INSERT INTO SomeThing SELECT … FROM SomeWhereElse…`.  Then you could get zero rows inserted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it is a wrong `copy+paste` but you're missing the type when defining `err`, you have some extra commas over the insert clause and you're returning a `CHAR(5)` that is truncating the value `NOTHING`. Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_1 (p_name VARCHAR(20), p_usernum INTEGER) RETURNING CHAR(7);

DEFINE err INTEGER;

ON EXCEPTION SET  err
    RETURN 'ERROR';
END EXCEPTION

ON EXCEPTION IN (746) SET err
RETURN 'NOTHING';
END EXCEPTION

INSERT INTO database1 (name, usernum)
VALUES (p_name, p_usernum);

IF DBINFO('sqlca.sqlerrd2') = 0
      THEN RAISE EXCEPTION 746;
   END IF;

RETURN 'YES';
END PROCEDURE;
```

Don't use the exception 150, you have a custom to use for this (746):

```
[infx1150@tardis ~]$ finderr 150
-150    The limits of the IBM Informix Demo Version have been exceeded.

You are using a demonstration version of the database server. This
version has severe limits on the number of tables and the size of the
tables that it can manage. The current operation causes it to exceed
one of those limits. Contact your IBM representative about buying
the production version of the software.


[infx1150@tardis ~]$ finderr 746
-746    message-string

You supply message-string for this message. You can apply this message
to error conditions that you specify in an SPL routine. The corrective
action for this error depends on the condition that caused it. You, the user,
define both the condition and the message text.


[infx1150@tardis ~]$
```

Comment: 746 is an error code reserved for this type of solutions where you want to custom the error message.

Comment: I have modified the stored procedure, this seems valid for it's purpose now.